# android studio convert responce data to readable marathi string and set in String variable

Tags: android, fonts

aim getting response data like ºÉÉ´É³äý·É®ú and i what to convert Marathi like सर्व्हर लिंक , how to convert and set into String variable ,

I had use Typeface for setting in textview , but when we set into String variable it show encoded value ºÉÉ´É³äý·É®ú

```
Typeface fontString = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_context.getAssets(), "DVSR0NTT.TTF");
```

String value = "ºÉÉ´É³äý·É®ú" 
i what to convert into 
String value = "सर्व्हर लिंक"